# Cannot install SQL Server (2012) PowerPivot for SharePoint, always fails SharePoint Version check

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, powerpivot

Trying to install a fresh install of `SharePoint 2010 (w/ SP1) Enterprise Evaluation` and `SQL Server 2012 PowerPivot for Sharepoint`.

The prerequisites clearly show that `SharePoint 2010 SP1` is needed, which we have installed.  However after when trying to install the SQL Server portion we consistently fail the rule `SharePoint version requirement for PowerPivot for SharePoint' validation in the`SQL Server` install process.

It seems the Evaluation version of SharePoint EE 2010 does not put the correct version # in the registry and thus it causes the install to fail.  However we are not ready to purchase a license without evaluating this tool to see if it meets our needs...

Here is the process we are following:

1. install SharePoint 2010
2. install SharePoint 2010 SP1
3. install SQL Server 2012 PowerPivot for SharePoint

Here is a screen shot of the error and the log file error.  We are completely stuck at this point, anyone run into this before?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

[This Article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldensetup/thread/30dbbdc6-56ab-47b1-92e3-f26fc20aa157) mentions an issue with the eval version of Sharepoint 2010 not correctly inserting the version into the registry but it does not mention how to fix this or work around..... if this helps anyone...

Comment: I am also currently trying to fix this problem. This Article: http://www.spjeff.com/2012/07/19/fixed-sharepoint-2013-rule-sharepoint-installation-requirements-for-powerpivot-for-sharepoint-failed/ has some registry key suggestions, however I have the same error as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by copying Registry Keys from another machine running SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

I used Process Monitor from SysInternals to identify the missing keys:

[image]

The contents of the resultant exported file are unfortunately too large to paste into this answer, but you can go into RegEdit on a SharePoint 2010 machine and export the following:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS\InstalledProducts]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDB]

[Disclaimer: I think the required registry file would be quite small, however I do not have time to refine it. You could also just export the whole \14.0\ key]

Comment: Would it be possible to export these keys to a flat file for me?  We dont have any other Sharepoint installs to compare to, but really need to get this up next week (hopefully) for a POC to fund the rest of the project.

Comment: I created a blog post around this. It is for SharePoint 2013 but could still work for your scenario. The .REG files are embedded in a Word document. http://andrewwhitten.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/sharepoint-2013-powerpivot-install-issue-please-install-sharepoint-before-you-install-powerpivot-for-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks, Ill give this a whirl today.  Appreciate the help.